# Git commit messages from pull request

Tags: git

How to get git commit message from a pull request, may be the request has more than one commits, how can I get these messages.
I know the command `git log` to get commit message, but I just want to show the relevant commit record for this pull request.

Comment: `git log` after `git pull origin xxx` cannot work?

Comment: I just want to show the relevant commit record for this pull requeset.

Comment: As @brian m. carlson's answer says, you can fetch the pull request first. You are supposed to know which branch this pull request will be merged to. Say it's master, and then you can run `git log master..pr-123` to find out the commits new to `master`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most code hosting platforms provide pull requests as a specially named ref. For example, on GitHub, pull requests are named `pull/ID/head`, where *ID* is the pull request number.

So if the main repository is named `origin`, you can check out the branch for pull request 123 by running `git fetch origin pull/123/head:pr-123`, which would create the branch `pr-123`. You can then run `git log` on it as normal.

If you're using GitLab or Bitbucket, they have similar configurations, but the names of the refs differ. You can consult the documentation for the platform you're using to see which refs they use.

Of course, these platforms also provide web interfaces you can use if you like.